# Different execution time of C++ program in cmd.exe vs Powershell

Tags: c++, windows

I was benchmarking this fairly simple program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void dotp(float *array1, float *array2, float *dest, size_t N) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      dest[i] += array1[i] * array2[i];
  }
}

float *newArray(int N) {
  float *x = new float[N];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    x[i] = i;
  }
  return x;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
  LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

  size_t LOOPS = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
  int N =  1024;

  float* x = newArray(N);
  float* y = newArray(N);
  float* z = newArray(N);

  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < LOOPS; ++i) {
    dotp(x, y, z, N);
  }
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
  ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
  ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
  ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

  printf("%lld\r\n", Frequency.QuadPart);
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
  printf("%lld\r\n", ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart);
  printf("%lld\r\n", Frequency.QuadPart);

  return 0;
}
```

and compiling it with `cl.exe /arch:AVX2 /O2 main.cpp`.

When running it in in cmd.exe, it takes about 1 seconds to run (I did many runs, no difference):

```
.\main.exe
10000000
1023448
10000000
```

However when running it in Powershell, it's substantially (and **consistently** over many runs, no matter what else is going on in my OS) faster:

```
 .\main.exe
10000000
620746
10000000
```

Using some simple shell commands corroborate what the performance counters say:

```
cmd /v:on /c "echo !time! & .\main.exe & echo !time!
11:59:11.38
10000000
1004120
10000000
11:59:12.39
```

```
 Measure-Command {.\main.exe}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 630
Ticks             : 6308918
TotalDays         : 7.30198842592593E-06
TotalHours        : 0.000175247722222222
TotalMinutes      : 0.0105148633333333
TotalSeconds      : 0.6308918
TotalMilliseconds : 630.8918
```

I printed the performance counter frequency before and after the profiled code in case there was a change and also set the priority class of the process just in case cmd.exe and Powershell treated it differently. No differences.

On top of that, **as soon as include iostream and use it to print something else**, the cmd.exe and Powershell give equivalent results (speed increase for cmd.exe, speed decrease for Powershell).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void dotp(float *array1, float *array2, float *dest, size_t N) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      dest[i] += array1[i] * array2[i];
  }
}

float *newArray(int N) {
  float *x = new float[N];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    x[i] = i;
  }
  return x;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
  LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

  size_t LOOPS = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
  int N =  1024;

  float* x = newArray(N);
  float* y = newArray(N);
  float* z = newArray(N);

  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < LOOPS; ++i) {
    dotp(x, y, z, N);
  }
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
  ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
  ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
  ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

  printf("%lld\r\n", Frequency.QuadPart);
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
  printf("%lld\r\n", ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart);
  printf("%lld\r\n", Frequency.QuadPart);
  std::cout << "blah" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

cmd.exe:

```
.\main.exe
10000000
776086
10000000
blah
```

Powershell:

```
.\main.exe
10000000
763109
10000000
blah
```

I'm not sure how to explain these discrepancies.

Answer (score 2):

Timing an application is a REALLY COMPLICATED deal. And the reasons for that is that you are NOT using a real time operational system.

Your processor stops executing your application to change the context to another process and so for so you have illusion of real time.

Check this to better undestand why your code wont work correctly:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Hope I helped

Comment: I think there’s more to it than just this. There’s a consistent difference between execution time (almost 400ms) between cmd.exe and Powershell no matter what the ambient OS environment is (open apps, running processes).

Comment: Could be some background, nevertheless I dont think you have a good parameters when measuring time. Another thing you can consider is the process priority. Check if both have the same priority, this could be the difference.

Comment: The code I shared already sets the process priority. My CPU is a 6 core i5-9600K idling at 1% CPU use. 400ms is an eternity in CPU time, so I’m not convinced that it’s simply a scheduling issue.

Comment: I will further research, run your code and check what i get! Talk to you soon